# Adding copyright information in dll

Tags: asp.net, dll, copyright-display

I have an ASP.NET project which refers some web services. When the project is published, the bin folder is created and it contains app_Webrefernces.dll.
Now I need to add copyright information to this dll. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not do this whilst building a DLL? Just put info in AssemblyInfo.cs file

Comment: Add copyright info in AssemblyInfo.cs like this [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Company name. 2011")]

Answer (score 4):

You can set the Metadata for your Assembly (DLL) like Title, Description, Copyright and more using

> [AssemblyInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You find this in Visual Studio

> To access this dialog box, select a project node in Solution Explorer, then on the
>       Project menu, click Properties. When the Project Designer appears, click
>       the Application tab. On the Application page, click the Assembly Information button.

or in the

**AssemblyInfo.cs** file

> {YourProject} / {Properties} / AssemblyInfo.cs

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Inside visual studio, 
go to solution explorer, expand your project's properties, overthere you an fill in AssemblyInfo.cs with basic copyright information for our dll.

This will be visible in compiled file on right clicking it and looking to the properties of the file.